# Use scanner connected to router's printer port (USB)

Tags: usb, router, scanner

I have the HP printer/scanner (DeskJet 2050 All-in-one) an wireless router D-Link Dir 320 with printer port (USB). So I connected the printer to this port, and can print form all computers at home.

Is it possible to use printer's scanner in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but isn't supported natively by the DIR-320.

The way to go about this would be to get a router that supports [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com) third party firmware, has a USB port and has USB support for scanners via [libsane within DD-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/USB) (SANE linux scanner software), and then have a scanner that is supported by libsane.

Then you would need [SaneTwain](http://sanetwain.ozuzo.net/) to interact with the scanner across the network.

There are lots of points in this chain that you might have difficulty getting to work.  It may be simpler to get a cheap nettop PC, run windows on it and plug the scanner into it.  Then "share" the scanner on the network by having people access the Windows box with RDP.

Comment: Yep... looks too complex for 21 century:)